# How to change current commit ID to master: git

Tags: git, github

Before I use to see my latest commit as master but now I only see the id.

e.g Nicholas ((615668f...)) MirrorMe

**What I want** 
: Nicholas (master) MirrorMe

I've tried to change it using " git branch -m "master" but it says "fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.".

My question is how do I make all my latest commits display master like before?

Comment: "now I only see the id", see it **where**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably checked out a local copy of a branch (like `origin/master`) or a commit, and are in a detached state (which is in read-only mode).

1. Delete your local master branch with `git branch -D master` (or safely rename master branch with `git checkout master; git branch -m save; git checkout 615668f`)
2. Recreate master from current commit with `git checkout -b master`

Comment: If that's the case, wouldn't it be safer and easier to simply `git checkout master`?

Comment: yes of course, if his master branch is in desired state

Comment: Thanks that helped

Answer (score 0):

Checkout from branch or commit id and then merge

```
git checkout branch-name or ID
```